# MvvmCross: How can I get the PCL to work with Profile 158? Is Windows 8 and WP8 SDK required to be installed?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have downloaded the latest Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4 and Xamarin Studio Version 4.2.1.
And, my PCL dll stopped working in VS2012 with my MvvmCross ios project. 
And, I can't get Profile 158 to work with my PCL class library.

See image.[image]

How can I get my Target Framework changed and work with Profile 158? I am using Windows 7 machine currently? And, I don't have WP8 sdk install because it is required to install on Windows 8 which I don't have it yet.

Let me know if I have to upgrade to Windows 8 first and download WP8 SDK to get this to work.

Thanks,

Wing

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the Profile is by manually editing the project file.

1. Right-click on your project and select "Unload Project"
2. Right-click and select "Edit [project name].csproj"
3. Find `<TargetFrameworkProfile>` tag and change it to
   `<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile158</TargetFrameworkProfile>`
4. Save. Right-clic on your project and select "Reload Project"

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171487(v=vs.90).aspx for detailed directions on editing the project file